# How to remove Skype from outlook.com?

Tags: outlook.com, skype-for-web

In the past, when Outlook.com was still Hotmail, I merged Skype with Hotmail and could communicate with my Skype contacts through the outlook.com website.

I have not used Skype for years now and I think that this whole integration with Skype makes loading a lot slower and it is something I don't want anymore.

Is there a way to remove Skype from outlook.com, or is it a standard feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, this is not possible. Please see the official answer below:

> **[How do I turn off Skype in Outlook.com?](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA34705/how-do-i-turn-off-skype-in-outlook-com)**
>
> Skype is fully integrated with Outlook.com and cannot be turned off.
>   We have received customer feedback that people would like the ability
>   to turn off Skype and we’re working on adding this feature – watch
>   this space.